# How to add hover text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons. When we click on first then second button activating and redirected to link, but the problem I am stuck on is I want to add fixed hover text on first button.

I also tried various codes like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bt1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $('#bt2').on('click', function() {
    $('<a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank"></a>')[0].click();
  })
  $("#bt2").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
$(function() {
  $("#div2").text('$5.7');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="storebutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" id="bt1" />
<input class="storebutton1" type="button" name="button" value=" Buy  Now " id="bt2" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: You can use `title` attribute if you don't have any special design idea.

Comment: add title in your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Tooltip, w3Schools have some greate examples on [tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp).

The JS part you seem to almost have figured out just edit the redirect to one of these:

Simulate a mouse click:

```
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
```

Simulate an HTTP redirect:

```
window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

```js
//add to cart button click
$(".addCart").click(function() {
  //enable the second button
  $(".buy").prop('disabled', false);
});

$(".buy").click(function() {
  //redirect to another page if second button is clicked
  window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 32px 0 0 20px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tooltip">
  <button class="addCart">Add to cart</button>
  <span class="tooltiptext">I'm a Tooltip!</span>
</div>

<button class="buy" href="http://newsite.test" disabled>Buy now</button>
```

Comment: Though good attempt, you should look into jQuery-ui. that does it for you. Still good to see it.

Comment: @Rajesh that is true, there are many libraries that have tooltips included I would use them instead of doing it myself most of the time.

Comment: Oh my God I can't Believe This Is my First Question on Stackoverflow . This is just like magic. Couple of days I am facing this error what you solve this very easy. I don't know how can I say thanks. no words appreciate from heart